# Dealing with CountVectorizer in other language

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, thai

I used CountVectorizer from Scikit-learn to count the occurrence of Thai word which already tokenized and then tried to vectorizing the text in Python 3

Code:

```
#-*-coding: utf-8 -*-

w_vector = ["การ", "ซ้อม"]
v = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=w_vector, token_pattern="(?u)\\b\\w*\\b", lowercase=False)

print(v.fit_transform(["การ ซ้อม"]).toarray())
```

Output:

```
[[1 0]]
```

Actually, it should be [[1 1]].

In my observation (I have done with many testing with Thai word dataset), I think there is a problem with Thai vowel which is " ้" (Thai vowel) in "ซ้อม", but for another case like "การ" (There is no vowel) it doesn't cause any problem for using CountVectorizer

Do you have any suggestion to adjust the CountVectorizer to recognize this case